# Can't render text to the side of a react icon and need some advice

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i'm  super perplexed and i'm surely doing something really stupid.. I just can't figure out where i'm going wrong. I'm rendering items on a nav bar that's outside the actual drop down nav bar menu, based on their roles.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";
import * as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa';
import * as AiIcons from 'react-icons/ai';
import * as IoIcons from 'react-icons/io';
import * as BsIcons from 'react-icons/bs';
import AuthService from "./services/auth.service";

import Login from "./components/login.component";
import Register from "./components/register.component";
import Home from "./components/home.component";
import Profile from "./components/profile.component";
//import BoardUser from "./components/board-user.component";
import BoardUser from "./components/tutorials-list.component";
import BoardModerator from "./components/board-moderator.component";
import BoardAdmin from "./components/board-admin.component";

// import AuthVerify from "./common/auth-verify";
import EventBus from "./common/EventBus";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import TutorialsList from "./components/tutorials-list.component";
import BigCalendar from "./components/CalendarComp";
import { Users } from './users/Index';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.logOut = this.logOut.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      showModeratorBoard: false,
      showAdminBoard: false,
      currentUser: undefined,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const user = AuthService.getCurrentUser();

    if (user) {
      this.setState({
        currentUser: user,
        showModeratorBoard: user.roles.includes("ROLE_MODERATOR"),
        showAdminBoard: user.roles.includes("ROLE_ADMIN"),
      });
    }
    
    EventBus.on("logout", () => {
      this.logOut();
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    EventBus.remove("logout");
  }

  logOut() {
    AuthService.logout();
    this.setState({
      showModeratorBoard: false,
      showAdminBoard: false,
      currentUser: undefined,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { currentUser, showModeratorBoard, showAdminBoard } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
         
          <div className="navbar-nav mr-auto">

         
            {showModeratorBoard && (
              console.log('is a mod')
            )}
            {showAdminBoard && (
            //  <div id='buttonTwo'>
            //       <Link to={"/profile"} className="topbar-nav">
            //       <AiIcons.AiOutlineProfile size={42} />
            //       <span class="caption"> Profile</span>

            //     </Link>
                <div id= 'buttonThree'>
                <Link to={"/users"} className="topbar-nav1">
                  <FaIcons.FaUsersCog size={42} />
                  <span class="caption" style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}> Users</span>
                </Link>
                  </div>
              // </div>   
              
            )}
            {currentUser && (
             <div id='button'>
           <a href="/login"   onClick={this.logOut}>
                <BsIcons.BsDoorOpen size={42} />
                <span class="caption" style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}> Log out</span>
              </a>
              <div id='buttonTwo'>
                  <Link to={"/profile"} className="topbar-nav">
                  <AiIcons.AiOutlineProfile size={42} />
                  <span class="caption" style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}> Profile</span>

                </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            )} 
          </div>
          {currentUser ? (
<Navbar />

          ) : (
            <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/login"} className="nav-link">
                  Login
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/register"} className="nav-link">
                  Sign Up
                </Link>
              </li>
            </div>
          )}
      
        <div className="container mt-3">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path={["/", "/home"]} component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
            <Route exact path="/tutorials-list" component={TutorialsList} />
            <Route exact path="/calendar" component={BigCalendar} />
            <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
            <Route path="/user" component={BoardUser} />
            <Route path="/mod" component={BoardModerator} />
            <Route path="/admin" component={BoardAdmin} />
            
          </Switch>
        </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default App;
```

this is my app.js, I'm trying to make the buttonTwo have the text line up to the side of it like the other navbar items.. Here's an example pic `https://gyazo.com/8ecc45c25a0f8ba2897b08ee04f04150`, I basically just want the text of profile to go to the side rather than under... here's my app.css

```
label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.card-container.card {
  max-width: 350px !important;
  padding: 40px 40px;
}

.card {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 20px 25px 30px;
  margin: 0 auto 25px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.profile-img-card {
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  display: block;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.home,
.reports,
.products {
  display: flex;
  height: 90vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.App {
    text-align: center;
}
#button{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1002;
  right: -5px;
  top: 20px;
  height: 8%;
  width: 8%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#buttonTwo{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1002;
  right: 220px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 8%;
  width: 8%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;

  
}
#buttonThree{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1002;
  right: 220px;
  top: 20px;
  height: 8%;
  width: 8%;
  display: inline-block;

}
.caption {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  }
```

could anyone give me any advice as to what i'm doing wrong... I'd be super appreciative. Like I said i'm just trying to render text to the side of the Profile item rather than under, thanks.

Comment: I ended up positioning the .caption with position:absoulute and it fixed the text. Not quite how i want it though but it works

Answer (score 0):

an easy way of doing it is using flex:

```js
<div className="parent">
    <Link to={"/profile"} className="button-class button-two topbar-nav">
      <AiIcons.AiOutlineProfile size={42} />
      <span class="caption" style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}> Profile</span>
    </Link>
    <Link to={"/otherpage"} className="button-class button-three topbar-nav">
      <AiIcons.AiOutlineProfile size={42} />
      <span class="caption" style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}> Otherpage</span>
    </Link>
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.button-class {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 8px;
}
```

you can see I only display two buttons, with same class rule on both of them (button-class), which sets them to be aligned to center between them with a small gap for spacing.
the parent is just displaying its children when even spaces between them (you can change to whatever you like)

I cleaned a bit the code, you don't need to wrap the link with another div.
so you can use the same idea to whatever you want if this doesn't fit for you